# Fail to use elasticsearch kuromoji plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, plugins, elasticsearch, bitnami

I am using Bitnami Elasticsearch AMI, and I followed instructions in order to install kuromoji pluging. I restarted the elasticsearch afterwards.

While trying to create a new index which uses it, I get the following faliure:

> {"error":"RemoteTransportException[[Scream][inet[/10.0.0.164:9300]][indices:admin/create]];
>   nested: IndexCreationException[[stories-ja] failed to create index];
>   nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find token
>   filter type [kuromoji_readingform] for [kuromoji_rf]]; nested:
>   NoClassSettingsException[Failed to load class setting [type] with
>   value [kuromoji_readingform]]; nested:
>   ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.kuromojireadingform.KuromojiReadingformTokenFilterFactory];
>   ","status":400}

The same index was created successfully locally, with the same elasticsearch version and plugin version, so my guess it is somehow related to the Bitnami environment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index creation failed since the plugin wasn't install on all of the nodes in the cluster.
Once I installed on nodes, it worked flawlessly.
Afterward, I found this is a known feature...